# Allow users to select among various default images while creating their profile if none is uploaded

Tags: 6, users, media

I'm using [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache), [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) and [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) to create my user profiles and I'd like to offer different default images if the user doesn't upload one.

Currently, ImageField offers a default image if none is uploaded but how can you show your user a lists of profile images in order to let them select one or upload their own ?

I'm looking to get something like this:

[image: Select different profile images]
Of course if the user upload one it will be used on their profile.

Any module you can recommend me or custom code to achieve this ? Does the [Gravatar module](http://drupal.org/project/gravatar) allow this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks to find, recommend, or suggest modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this module - [Avatar Selection](http://drupal.org/project/avatar_selection).

Does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: And it supports imagecache ?

Comment: I believe it does, yeah - see this project issue queue thread about it: http://drupal.org/node/431500

Comment: Hum, so I had a look at it and it's almost what I'm looking for, it's used for avatars which imply you allow images for users (`admin/user/settings`) but I'm using ImageCache and also ImageField which is used to determine the profile image. So it's quite there but not. I'd rather have a "ImageCache Default Selection" module :).

Comment: Ok we finally rewrote our field and use the `$user->picture` to use this module. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Gravatar module currently allows the site administrator to choose the default image to use if the user doesn't have a Gravatar (including all the choices you've presented above), but this applies on a site-wide basis --- users cannot choose their own Gravatar variant, though they can still upload their own image if desired.

If you do end up developing support for per-user Gravatar variant switching, consider supporting this feature request, which anticipates similar functionality: http://drupal.org/node/1172546 .

Comment: I'm not very fond of using Gravatar for this solution because I can't control the default images.